# Show column when ever the user input text in the search bar

Tags: html, css, angular, layout, multiple-columns

I'm doing Angular project and wondering how I can display the middle column when ever the user input any text in the search bar.

So right now, I have search bar for user input and three flex columns. The middle column are hidden when the page is open but I want it to show when ever the user put any text in the search box. Any help will be really appreacited.

```css
.left {
  flex: 2;

}

.right {
  flex: 1;

}
.center{
  flex: 1;
  display: none;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 95vw;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Middle Column --!>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="chart-header">Charts</div>  
        <div>Chart will display here</div>
    </div>
    
 
 <!-- My user input/ search bar --!>
 
 <input  [formControl]="inputCtrl" matInput class="input">
```

Comment: you should improve the question, it's pretty unclear

Comment: @fercaveri, I fixed my questions. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// .html file      
 <div class="center" *ngIf="showColumn">
            <div class="chart-header">Charts</div>  
            <div>Chart will display here</div>
        </div>


   //.ts file
   showColumn = false;
     this.form.get('inputCtrl').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.showColumn = true;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe valueChanges event of form controller

TS File

```
this.form.get("inputCtrl").valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
  this.displayStyle = 'block';
})
```

HTML File

```
<div class="center" [ngStyle]="{'display':displayStyle}>
    <div class="chart-header">Charts</div>  
    <div>Chart will display here</div>
</div>
```